# How can I set a button to create a cookie with an increased numerical name and unique value (based on a variable) each time it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am trying to create a button that creates a new cookie with an increased numeric value as it's name and a different value (which comes from a variable), each time it is clicked. But, I can't get it to work.

This is what I have:

```
var date = new Date()
date.setTime(date.getTime() + 7*24*60*60*1000); 

var num=1;
  function addCookie() {

        var expString = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        var cookievalue=escape(document.button.addpart.value) + ";";
        document.cookie=num + "=" + cookievalue + expString + "; path=/my-quote/"; 
        num++;
    }
```

Then the html is:

```
<button name="addpart"; value="<?php $pn ?>"; onclick='addCookie()'>ADD</button>
```

I started with the following code (which worked, but just created a new cookie with the name 1 and value 1, then 2 and 2, 3 and 3 etc. I adapted it, so I think that's where I have gone wrong or missed something:

```
  var num=1;
  function addCookie() {
     document.cookie=num+"="+num;
     num++;
  }
```

Updated code

```js
var date = new Date() date.setTime(date.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var num = 1;

function addCookie() {
  var expString = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
  var cookievalue = escape(document.querySelector("[name=addpart]").value) + ";";
  document.cookie = num + "=" + cookievalue + expString + "; path=/my-quote/";
}
```

Comment: `document.button.addpart.value` does not look like a correct item - perhaps `document.querySelector("[name=addpart]").value`

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for your suggestion. It now seems to be registering the cookie, but only name=1 value=null and this simply resets each time I click the button. 
`var date = new Date()
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + 7*24*60*60*1000); 
  
  var num=1;
    function addCookie() {
    
    var expString = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    var cookievalue=escape(document.querySelector("[name=addpart]").value) + ";";
    document.cookie=num + "=" + cookievalue + expString + "; path=/my-quote/"; 
    
   }`

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting unformattable comments. That said: `var num = +document.querySelector("[name=addpart]").value +1; document.cookie = num + "=" + num + ";" + expString + "; path=/my-quote/";`